# Print out properly the output

Tags: c

I am running this

```
ls -l | myprogram
```

basically I want to print out output in proper way. when we have `ls -l` independently there can be many lines. Each line contains 8 elements. So I want to print it in a way `ls -l` give output, but skip two elements at the top (total number). For example, `ls -l` gives us

```
total 3
-rwx------ 1 cre university 8381 Sep 24 21:04 a.out
drwx------ 5 cre university 4096 Sep 16 19:36 file2
-rwx------ 1 cre university 8499 Sep 25 00:50 file1
```

I need `ls -l | myprogram`:

```
-rwx------ 1 cre university 8381 Sep 24 21:04 a.out
drwx------ 5 cre university 4096 Sep 16 19:36 file2
-rwx------ 1 cre university 8499 Sep 25 00:50 file1
```

This is that I have so far. It just print all elements in one line. 
Have no idea how to implement the part when they in lines with 8 elements. After that I want to compare sizes of the files. Please help, beginner here!

Comment: Not a direct answer, but did you try `ls -l | tail -n +2`?

Comment: whats your expected output? you werent that clear

Comment: @SukkoPera `sed '1d'` does the same thing. However in this case I'd vote for `tail`

Comment: Sure @starrify, I'm sure there are at least another dozen ways to do the same thing :).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can find the "\n\n" in your input stream which is the empty line. From there you will get the rest of the contents of the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

In the do while loop, you could try adding a "\n" to the printf statement, like below:

```
do {    
    result=scanf("%s",string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
} while (result!=EOF);
```

However, the do/while isn't very safe - see my code below.

If you need to skip the "total X" line, you could do it in one of two ways: 
Know that it's the first line and skip it or do a string comparison for "total X" and then skip it.  I'd probably go for the later option, given that it's going to be there - unless, of course, ls changes anytime soon.  To be totally safe, a regex would probably be safest, but longer to implement.

Here's an example. Notice I changed it from a do/while to a do.  That's because you need to check if result == EOF before you use it and the do/while from above doesn't give you a chance to do it. The while is safer.

```
 while (EOF != (result = scanf("%s", string))) {
    // skip line containing "total X"
    if (strncmp(result, "total ", sizeof("total ")) == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    printf("%s\n", string);
 }
```

Disclaimer - I haven't compiled this, so not quite sure if sizeof("total ") is syntactically correct, but the idea should be.

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

Although

> "ls -l | tail -n +2" 
>   is good answer. If you want to do it with your code, simply check the start of the line

```
...
 while (NULL != fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin)) { 
    if (strncmp(string, "total", strlen("total")) == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    printf("%s ", string);
 }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to skip certain lines, those that match patterns.  This is really better done with a language that does regular expressions well (ex: awk, perl, ruby, python, et al).

You could read each line, but match and skip certain lines that easily detected patterns, such as lines that begin with "total", empty lines, and the "." and ".." special directories,

```
linebuffer[1024];
while( fgets(linbuffer,sizeof(linebuffer),stdin) ) {
    if( strlen(linebuffer) < 2 ) continue; //short lines
    if( strncmp(linebuffer,"total",strlen("total")==0 ) continue; //line begins with "total"
    //do you want to skip ".", ".."?
    if( strcmp(linebuffer+strlen(linebuffer)-2,".\n")==0 ) continue; //skip ".", ".."
    printf("%s",linebuffer); //or use puts
}
```

Another approach is to open the directory, read it, and decode the file information (see stat(2)), this will skip the "total" line rather handily,

```
int res;
struct stat statbuf;
char pathname[1024];
DIR* dir;
struct dirent  *dp=NULL;
char* fname;

if( !(dir=opendir(dname)) ) {
    int ec=errno;
    printf("error:-1:cannot opendir %s\n",dname,ec);
    return(-1);
}
while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    //printf("file: %s\n",dp->d_name); fflush(stdout);
    if( strcmp(dp->d_name,".")==0 ) continue;
    if( strcmp(dp->d_name,"..")==0 ) continue;
    fname=dp->d_name;
    //call stat(2) here on the file,
    sprintf(pathname,"%s/%s",dname,dp->d_name);
    if( (res=stat(dname, &statbuf)) == -1) {
        int ec=errno;
        printf("error:-1:cannot stat %s (%d)\n",pathname,ec);
        return(-1);
    }
    //printf("dirwatch:check (%s)\n",pathname);
    print_fileinfo(&statbuf,dp->d_name); //left as an exercise for the poster
}
closedir(dir);
```

You will need to decode and print the stat(2) information,

```
int
print_fileinfo(stat* statbuf, char* name)
{
    //decode rwx bits for owner, group, and other
    //lookup owner and group names
    //file size is part of statbuf
    //file type (regular, directory, et al) is part of statbuf
}
```

You will need to look at the stat(2) man page, but here are some useful values, macros,

```
   All of these system calls return a stat structure, which contains the following fields:

       struct stat {
           dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
           ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
           mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
           nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
           uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
           gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
           dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
           off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
           blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
           blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
           time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
           time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
           time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
       };

   The following POSIX macros are defined to check the file type using the st_mode field:

       S_ISREG(m)  is it a regular file?

       S_ISDIR(m)  directory?

       S_ISCHR(m)  character device?

       S_ISBLK(m)  block device?

       S_ISFIFO(m) FIFO (named pipe)?

       S_ISLNK(m)  symbolic link?  (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)

       S_ISSOCK(m) socket?  (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)

   The following flags are defined for the st_mode field:

       S_IFMT     0170000   bit mask for the file type bit fields
       S_IFSOCK   0140000   socket
       S_IFLNK    0120000   symbolic link
       S_IFREG    0100000   regular file
       S_IFBLK    0060000   block device
       S_IFDIR    0040000   directory
       S_IFCHR    0020000   character device
       S_IFIFO    0010000   FIFO
       S_ISUID    0004000   set UID bit
       S_ISGID    0002000   set-group-ID bit (see below)
       S_ISVTX    0001000   sticky bit (see below)
       S_IRWXU    00700     mask for file owner permissions
       S_IRUSR    00400     owner has read permission
       S_IWUSR    00200     owner has write permission
       S_IXUSR    00100     owner has execute permission
       S_IRWXG    00070     mask for group permissions
       S_IRGRP    00040     group has read permission
       S_IWGRP    00020     group has write permission
       S_IXGRP    00010     group has execute permission
       S_IRWXO    00007     mask for permissions for others (not in group)
       S_IROTH    00004     others have read permission
       S_IWOTH    00002     others have write permission
       S_IXOTH    00001     others have execute permission
```